# iText7 Array of Tables

Tags: c#, arrays, pdf, nullreferenceexception, itext7

the code snippet will compile but when run a *NullReferenceException* is thrown. It says "object not set to an instance of an object". The code is created using .NET Core 3.1 on VS2019.
I could not find any evidence whether this code could run.
Many thanks for any help.

```
 class Program
    {        
        static PdfDocument pdfTable;
        static Document document;
        static string destination;
              
        static void Main()
        {            
            destination = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents", "SRC_Selection.pdf");
            pdfTable = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(destination));
            document = new Document(pdfTable); 
            
            // some usual MySql-stuff here

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                List<Table> tables = new List<Table>();
                for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) tables.Add(new Table(1, true)); 
                Cell[] cell = new Cell[reader.FieldCount];

                int i = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                { 
                   For (int j = 0; j < reader.FieldCount-1; j++)        
                   {
                        cell[j] = new Cell(1, 1)   
                          .SetFontSize(10)
                          .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT)
                          .Add(new Paragraph(reader.GetString(j)));
                
                        tables[i].AddCell(cell[j]);  // exception thrown here!
                   }

                   document.Add(tables[i]).Add(newline);
                   i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add more context to the question.. How `reader`/`document` are created? At which instruction the exception is thrown?

Comment: Added some more code to show the dependencies. There is not much special in the code, just basic database structures, where a selection of lines from a PDF are copied in to different tables of a new PDF-file. It's like a multiple choice form.

Comment: ... meanwhile found the solution. I made use of List<Table> tables and initialize the list elements by Table(1, false). Then I could get  individual tables by document.Add(tables[i]);

Answer (score 0):

The NullReferenceException you are getting is likely due to the fact that you have declared an array of Table objects (`Table[] table = new Table[10];`), but you have not initialized each element of the array. Check the below code.

```
for (int j = 0; j < reader.FieldCount; j++)
{
    table[i] = new Table(reader.FieldCount - 1); // Initialize the table with the appropriate number of columns

    cell[j] = new Cell(1, 1)
        .SetFontSize(10)
        .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT)
        .Add(new Paragraph(reader.GetString(j)));

    table[i].AddCell(cell[j]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, I can see it now. Your solution is equivalent to the one with the list elements. I missed the initialization.